# mySQL IF statement, how to match a value and add multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

While doing a project for the school I work at I needed to do some IF type of statements in my mySQL Query. Things like if they are a HS student did they submit this form.

So for instance I would love to be able to check if multiple forms had been sent to the school based on a persons grade level and come back with all students missing some sort of form

```
SELECT studentId 

FROM students 

WHERE formBirthCertificate != 1 AND anotherForm != 1 and familyForm  != 1

IF (gradeLevelId >= 9 then formHighSchool  !=1)//they are High School student did they submit a form

IF  (gradeLevelId >= 5 then formStudent !=1)
```

It is not an either or type or condition, it is more if the person is in high school (gradelevelId 9), check to see they also submitted this form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You already have it correct:  `SELECT studentId FROM students WHERE (formBirthCertificate != 1) AND (anotherForm !=1 ) AND (familyForm != 1)` is valid SQL (I added the parenthesis for clarification only, it should work without them).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT studentId, 
(case when gradeLevelId >= 9 then 0 ELSE 1 end) AS formHighSchool, 
(case gradeLevelId >= 5 then 0 ELSE 1 end) AS formStudent
FROM students 
WHERE formBirthCertificate != 1 AND anotherForm != 1 and familyForm  != 1
```

Should return something like:

```
studentId   formHighSchool   formStudent
    1             0              1
    2             0              0
    3             1              0
    4             1              1
   ...           ...            ...
```